# Add @click event to text in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onclick

I am trying to add a click event to a text add states in description method stated below. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
<div>
 class="alert-container"
 v-for="alert in alerts"
 >
 <div class="alert-item">
   <div class="alert-info">
    {{alert.sender}}
  </div>
   <div v-if="alert.alert_type === 'urgent'">
    <div class="alert-description">{{ addMethod(alert.description) }}</div>
   </div>
   <div v-else class="alert-description" v-html="alert.description"></div>
 </div>
</div>


<script>
  export default {
   methods: {
      addMethod(text) {
        return text + '-' + add click event to here to the description text just so when the user clicks on the event below evacuation method runs.
      },
      evacuation() {
       console.log("Leave the building now.")
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just render the description text then add the click avent to the wrapper element :

```
<div class="alert-description" @click="evacuation">{{ alert.description }} - </div>
```

*adding the event inside a string and rendering it using `v-html` will not be interpreted.*

Comment: The issue is I don't want the entire description to a click event. I want to addition text to description. 

description + click here 

after clicking on click here it runs evacuation()

Comment: do you want that only the substring `click here` to be clickable?

Comment: it's not possible to add a click event inside a string then run it

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="alert-description">{{ alert.description }} - <div class="evacuation">Click here</div></div>
```

this is how I solved my problem